# Load 'div' a few seconds after 'body' is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to load the "text-container" div a few seconds after the image pops up. I know i should do it with javascript and I already tried this code

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){

var timer = setTimeout("showText()",7000)
}
function showText(){
document.getElementByClass("text-container").style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>
```

While leaving the text-container as hidden: `style="visibility:hidden;"`

```
<div class="notification-container">
  <div class="image-container">
      <img class="image" src="{image}" />

  </div>

  <div class="text-container">
    <div class="title">
      <span class='keyword name'>{name}</span>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

If you need extra information let me know!

Comment: `I already tried multiple times`--> we need to see what have you tried and where you failed

Comment: I mean, you just start with `display: none` and then in javascript put a function in a `setTimeout` that justs sets the `display:visible` again.

Comment: Ill try that and i'll let you know if it works. thanks

Comment: setTimeout receives a pointer to a function or the function itself, not a string with the name of the function

Comment: Do you need it to *look* like the text content is loaded later? Or do you  need it to *actually* be loaded later (for bandwidth or performance reasons?)

Comment: just as stated in kevinniels' answer i need to load the text 5 seconds after the animation has started loading. no need for better performance or bandwidth reasons..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementByClass("text-container").style.display="initial";
},7000);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called "LazyLoading". The aim is to dynamically load images, scripts, or any files after the DOM has been made to allow pages to load faster.

They are many plugins and libraries in javascript that can make this, for exemple [jQuery Lazy](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/)

It's often really simple to use it, you just have to follow the documentation and if you're not really good at JS, no problems it's nearly only copy / paste code to make it run !

Comment: thank you! but actually im trying to do some alerts for streaming. im using muxy...

Answer (score 0):

You can do Transitions using CSS if that helps you.

Alternatively, The best method is to use Javascript.

It shouldn't be very hard with javascript, The most likely error I think would be you won't have attached your JS file properly or some typo mistake.

In Js, it is just this much code to enable it.

```
//Declare timeout function 
//Add class you wanna add or remove (you can set CSS accordingly)
//Give timer (in milliseconds)

setTimeout(function(){ /
 document.getElementById('footer').classList.remove('hide');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery to apply a delay to your element(s) in milliseconds

```
$( "document" ).ready(function() {
$( ".notification-container" ).fadeIn( 400 );
$( ".text-container" ).fadeIn( 400 ).delay( 500 ) ;
});
```